# Can not get checkbox's to be mutually exclusive with simple form

Tags: javascript

I want 2 checkbox's that are mutually exclusive. In the example below when you click on one it will work for like one cycle then working as they will both become selected.  Is this not possible?  What is the best approach for something like this ?  #states seems so limiting, but I don't want to quite give up on FAPI.

I am starting to suspect #states is mainly just useful for collapsing/expanding fieldsets.

```
function form_example_stacko_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['ourfieldset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Fieldset'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);
$form['ourfieldset']['checkbox1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#states' => array(
      'unchecked' => array(
        array(':input[name="checkbox2"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),
      ),
   ),
);
$form['ourfieldset']['checkbox2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
   '#states' => array(
      'unchecked' => array(
        array(':input[name="checkbox1"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),
     ),
  ),
);  

return $form;
}
```

Comment: any reason you dont want to go with radio button?

Comment: I prefer checkbox for visual reasons, but at this point I can try radio.  I also wanted separate inputs as I can easily put #description on each option. I do not want radios because they seem more limiting in the layout but at this point I just want a decent and workable implementation.

Comment: Well for now I've just went back to radios as it works.

Comment: You can also use jQuery to de-select the one if the other is clicked